# improve the quality of an audio file of two speakers at different distances

Tags: audio, audio-player, audio-processing

I am recording a conversation between two speakers. The first speaker is holding the mic and the second speaker is setting 6 Feet away from the mic. This means that the volume of the first speaker is always higher. Is there is a way to process the audio file to make both at the same level? or at least what kind of audio processing field I need to look at to answer this question?

Comment: Audio Compressor / Limiters could be useful in getting the level more consistent.

Comment: Is this just for a single file? Or do you need an automated programmatic solution?

Comment: I am looking for doing this automatically

Comment: **(1)** Check the sound levels in an audio editor, note the typical sound levels (range) when the sound is low. **(2)** In code, you decode the audio to PCM and that gives you the same values (that you saw in audio editor, where the PCM values draw the waveform) that can be checked for amplitude levels. If you find a group of samples with low volume then you increase the values, after saving as WAV or encoding to MP3 the playback should be of higher sound. It's not a perfect solution (they cost money) but it's a start if you want to do the processing yourself.

Comment: checkout this repo: https://github.com/lordmulder/DynamicAudioNormalizer